# How to format this query in RavenDB

Tags: linq, ravendb

Given a document that looks like this:

```
public class Post {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags {get; set;}
}
```

How do you create this linq query for the RavenDB linq provider.

```
from post in Posts
where post.Tags.Contains(someTag)
select post
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from post in Session.Query<Post>()
where post.Tags.Any(tag => tag == someTag)
select post
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid. I had it in my head that Any would only return the first post that had a matching tag. I helped myself prove my thought in a unit test by having a poorly prepared sample in an in memory database. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson,
Something like this:

```
 from p in session.Query<Post>()
 where p.Tags.Any(tag => tag == someTag) 
 select p;
```